# Cant access my website through its IP address

Tags: apache, http, ip, web-hosting

I have hosting with godaddy with a private IP address. I am able to access my websites and others via the domain name, but not via IP Address.

I am now trying to access the HTTP via port 80 but it gives an error that the website is not setup.

Are there any workarounds on turning allowing accessing the website and other folders through the IP address over `http`?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like you were on a managed webpack that grants you access to the to-be-served content but not to the webserver or its config itself.

What you are experiencing there is an effect of a technique called [virtual-hosts](/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) in which multiple sites are tied to one IP address. For this to work in the realm of HTTP, the [`Host`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) header got introduced in HTTP/1.1. It allows clients to send a domain name for which they want to receive content.

If you request a raw IP, though, the `Host` header won't look like `Host: example.com` but rather like `Host: 123.45.67.89`. The server will not be able to associate a domainname with this as it is unlikely to be found elsewhere in the request. Therefore, it will be forced to serve content out of its default document directory which usually contains further documentations regarding the further configuration of the webserver in question. Linux distributions like to add additional informations specific to them. Check if you see any mentioning of e.g. Debian, RedHat, or Centos.

I am not sure if this is fixable. Usually webservers like Apache support [IP-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html). If a masshoster like godaddy is really going to address this is uncertain. Try to contact their support and see.

Answer (score -2):

1]If you are using host headers, make sure you have a DNS entry pointing your URL to your IP

2]Telnet port 80 from a machine outside your network.If it fails then check with your ISP that port 80 should not block in firewall.